# Using Wordpress to build membership Page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax, user-registration, membership

I wanna built a membership page, which does have the regular stuff for non-members like Landing Page, One-Pager, Contact stuff, imprint etc... and than there should be some sort of registration and if you are registered and paid via Paypal, you can access premium content.

I came up with the idea to use Wordpress, because I can create the overall external website with it, and it has already the whole user management framework like registering, login, stay-loggedin via cookies, authentication features, user-administration and roles, etc...

I'm just wondering what would be the best way to code my own stuff into wordpress to make it as easy as possible for me to maintain the code and also be able to use it maybe in future without wordpress.

My membership site needs to have some configurable forms which should use auto completion via Ajax, than some dashboards and graphs which should look nice and be interactive (e.g. via JS-Plotting), etc.

I came up with two solutions, and I'm asking you to give me the feedback whether it's a good or bad idea or whether there are better ideas in general:

- I could code my own plugin, create single pages as normal using the wp-admin, also link them in the menu and just make those pages contain some shortcodes which will get replaced by my plugin with actual content.
- I could simply change the template-code, having one additional include statement in the section where normally the page content is printed. This include statement would include some main logic file which would than decide based on the URL-slug which sub-module to include, which would do the overall logic like printing, validating forms, calculate stuff to be output to JS-graphs.

What's your idea?

Btw:
Would it be possible, from my PHP files, to use some styled things from the Theme? E.g. in case I use Avada, can I somehow use the Avada Shortcodes to build some good-looking Boxes, or also like a row with 3 responsive columns, from my own PHP file? Or are those AvadaBuilder tags only parsed when going through the whole Wordpress Engine?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several membership plugins or customer area plugins. MemberPress is an easy one to setup.